# MediaRecorder API not able to record at higher framerate

Tags: javascript, screen-recording, web-mediarecorder

I am currently working on a project and need to be able to make a recording of my screen and save it locally to my computer.

The recording is being saved as a webm, but everyone of them has a really bad framerate of usually around 10-15 fps. Is there a way to increase the framerate for recording?

I am able to increase the quality of the recording by playing around with the MediaRecorder options and codecs, but this doesn't seem to affect the framerate I am getting at all.

Here is the code I am using to make my recording:

```
const options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp9.00.41.8.00.01"',
        videoBitsPerSecond: 800 * Mbps,
        videoMaximizeFrameRate: true,
    };
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options); 

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;

startBtn.onclick = e => {
    mediaRecorder.start();
    startBtn.innerHTML = 'Recording';
}

stopBtn.onclick = e => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    startBtn.innerHTML = 'Start';
}

function handleDataAvailable(e) {
    recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}

async function handleStop() {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm'
    });

    const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

    const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
        buttonLabel: 'Save video',
        defaultPath: `vid-${Date.now()}.webm`
    });

    console.log(filePath);

    if (filePath) {
        writeFile(filePath, buffer, () => console.log('video saved successfully'));
    }
}
```

I have looked through the MDN documentation and haven't found anything about it. I also tried using different codecs with different parameters, but the results are always the same.

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I'm playing an existing video file and I wonder if playing it at half the speed then duplicating the speed can give me the double amount of fps, any insights would be appreciated

Comment: @IvanCastellanos Why are you trying to capture a video file you're playing back?  Why not simply transcode from the original?

Comment: @Brad I said "existing video" to keep it short, but I'm actually recording a canvas to merge 2 videos (one is bg, the other an overlay) I have in memory/blobs (one is from user's webcam, the other from Youtube). Its for a Chrome extension; I already gave up on all that and will do it on the backend instead, even if is a lot more costly (in money).

Comment: @IvanCastellanos You can use `canvas.captureStream()` for this, and you'll have a lot better performance.  If you'd prefer to drop the canvas and just use the browser engine directly, you can get decent performance by using a tab capture, since you have an extension running anyway.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, already tried that using a library that does that called "video-stream-merger" but the performance is not good enough, mixing while recording makes the webcam fps drop too much, but the other way of recording the webcam only is also bad because webcam is recorded in real-time and canvas.captureStream is also on real-time, and as expected recording the recording reduces the quality too much; I also tried ffmpeg.wasm with node-ytdl-core but that comes with his own set of issues. I didn't know about tab capture, I will check it out (but tbh probably will stick with backend processing)

Comment: @IvanCastellanos I have a Node.js application set up for automating the tab capture and outputting video to FFmpeg, Gstreamer, etc., designed to run server-side for creating video streams.  If you're interested at all, feel free to e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.  The source code is available for licensing.

Answer (score 0):

The framerate you're getting is typical for any standard screen capture.

The only way to go faster is to utilize the GPU's specific capability to capture and encode.  This is out of scope for the web APIs.

Comment: This answer is not useful, I'm sure there are many ways to workaround this issue even if not all that ideal e.g. recording at half the speed and modifiy the binary to play at twice the speed, or recording the same thing multiple times and try to merge them into one.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos It's a screen capture, so if you're recording something at half speed, you're losing frames from the source material.  It's quite simply the way this works.  You're welcome to post a different answer.  The good news is that since this answer was written, Chrome *can* accelerate the capture of certain things, such as other browser tabs.  It also has better support for hardware codecs.  The point of the answer still stands though, in that you don't have much control over this, since the bottleneck is in the browser implementation.